# How to comment a line based on the word it starts with?

Tags: sed, vi

sample file content:

```
--------------------
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=wls1.ebs-testsrvrs.com
# oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall : Add NOZEROCONF=yes
NOZEROCONF=yes
--------------------
```

I want to comment all the lines that start with "HOST"

Answer (score 17):

In `vi`:

```
:%s/^HOST/#&/
```

or

```
:g/^HOST/s//#&/
```

The `%` in the first command means "in the whole buffer", and is a short way of saying `1,$`, i.e. from the first line to the last. `&` in the replacement part of the substitution will be replaced by the whole text matched by the pattern (`^HOST`).

The second command applies the substitution (`s///`) to all lines matching `^HOST` using the global (`g`) command, which `vi` inherited from the `ed` line editor. In the second case, the `s///` command uses an empty regular expression.  This make it reuse the most recently used regular expression (`^HOST` in the `g` command).  The replacement is the same as in the first command.

With `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's/^HOST/#&/' input >output
```

or

```bsh
sed '/^HOST/s//#&/' input >output
```

in the same manner as in `vi` (`sed` always applies all commands to every line of the input stream, so we don't use anything like `%` or `g` explicitly with `sed`).

---

To *remove* the comment character for the line that starts with `#HOST`:

```bsh
sed 's/^#HOST/HOST/' input >output
```

or

```bsh
sed '/^#HOST/s/.//' input >output
```

In the second of the above two commands, the `s///` command is applied to all lines that start with `#HOST`.  The `s///` command just deletes the first character on the line.

The `vi` equivalent of the two commands are

```
:%s/^#HOST/HOST/
```

and

```
:g/^#HOST/s/.//
```

respectively

Answer (score 4):

Use sed with the `-i` option to edit the file in place. (A backup copy of the original will be saved as `file.txt.bak`).
`sed -i.bak 's/^\(HOST.*\)/#\1/g' file.txt`

To read the regular expression part: 
The `^` matches the beginning of the line.

The `()` grabs the matching text into a temporary internal variable (`\1`).

The `\` is needed before the `(` characters, since your shell will steal them otherwise.

The `.*` matches 0 or more characters.

So, starting from the front of the line, it matches the string `HOST` followed by any text, up until the newline. If the line doesn't match, leave it as is. If it does match, then the `#\1` will print `#` followed by the text in between the `()`.

Answer (score 3):

Perl one liner:

```
perl -pe 's/^HOST/#$&/' file
```

Or, to edit the file in place:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^HOST/#$&/' file
```

#### Explanation

The `-pe` means **p**rint every input line after applying the script given by `-e`. The `s/foo/bar/` is the replacement operator and will replace the first instance of `foo` with `bar` on every line. Here, we are replacing lines starting with `HOST` (`^` means the beginning of the line) with a `#` and whatever was matched (`$&` is a special variable storing what was matched). So, we replace `HOST` with `#HOST`.

Answer (score 2):

Doable through `awk` as following:

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /^HOST/){print "#"$0}else{print $0}}' file > file.conf
```

`awk` will read the data from your file, if the line start with `HOST` it will print the line with `#` at the beginning, if not will print it as is.

`>` to save the outputs in `file.conf`

Comment: The `cat` is not needed if you tell `awk` to read from `file` directly. Also, you have a syntax error in the Awk script.

Comment: This can be simplified even further with `awk '$0~/^HOST/{$0="#"$0};1' input.txt` .

Answer (score 1):

perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/^HOST/){print "#$_"} else { print}' input.txt                                  
--------------------
NETWORKING=yes
#HOSTNAME=wls1.ebs-testsrvrs.com
# oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall : Add NOZEROCONF=yes
NOZEROCONF=yes
--------------------
```

This simple one-liner iterates over all lines , checking if line starts with `HOST` and appending `#` to it, otherwise we go to `else` statement, which simply prints the line unaltered.

Python version of the same thing would be the following:

```
python -c "import sys;print '\n'.join([ '#' + l.strip() if l.startswith('HOST') else l.strip()  for l in sys.stdin  ])" < input.txt
```

This however works slightly differently, by building up list ( or array ) of lines , inserting conditionally line itself or the line with `#` appended. Ultimately, the array is joined into a one large string with items separated by newlines, and printed out.